# Video is not playing in the server but playing local in iPad?

Tags: ios, html, ipad

I am using html5 `<video>` tag to play a video in the iPad/iPhone its playing  good in local but when i update to the server i am just getting the play icon and its stuck there itself.

```
<video controls="true" preload id=videoContainer>
    <source src=video/abc.mp4 type=video/mp4>
    <source src=video/abc.ogg type=video/ogg>
    <source src=video/abc.webm type=video/webm>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess and added the following lines in it

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```